# Jmeter Integrated Windows Authentication (NTLM)

Tags: jmeter, ntlm-authentication

I am a rookie when it comes to Jmeter and I am struggling to get a HTTP Request to run successfully (even for 1 iteration).

The Site being tested is an Intranet site used by staff. In terms of accessing via any browser, the homepage loads (having authenticated me as a user through my Domain Login/Password - through logging in to my laptop). From what I can gather from tools such as FIDDLER:

- GET request to the server sent, Server response is 401 unauthorized (WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate)
- GET REQUEST header sent back with Authorization: Negotiate HASH, Server response is 401 Unauthorized with a different WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate HASH
- GET REQUEST sent back with same Authorization: Negotiate HASH as received in previous SERVER response. Server responds with HTTP 200.

I am struggling to get the above working in JMETER. I have tried by capturing the output from Blazemeter Chrome plugin and saving as .jmx file but replaying this results in

div id="header">h1>**Server Error**

h2>401 - **Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials**.
  h3>**You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied**.

Any ideas as to how I should go about getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.........

Comment: Ok have managed to get some success here!

Answer (score 0):

JMeter comes with [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) which you can use to bypass NTLM authentication challenge. Just add it to your Test Plan and provide the following values:

- Username: your Windows domain user name
- Password: your Windows domain password
- Domain: your Windows domain
- Mechanism: `BASIC_DIGEST`

The HTTP Authorization Manager should automatically handle auth flow. See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article for more details if required.